# Maximum size of GKTurnBasedMatch matchData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, game-center, gamekit

I've been searching for a definitive answer on this, but I get some inconsistent answers. Apple docs state 64k bytes. However, online I find multiple sources that say 4k bytes is the max. Is this a difference between iOS 5 and iOS 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was 4KB, now its 64KB.

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=02012012a

Comment: From the source: “We’ve recently increased the data size for turn-based matches from 4 kb to 64 kb, so...”. It might be a typo, but this seems to say the limit is 64 kilo-bits, not bytes. Any clarity on this point?

Answer (score 0):

Definative, or not, but I think that the previous limit was 4 kB, and that that limit now has been raised to 64k. Not 100% sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a read only property called:  `matchDataMaximumSize` of the `GKTurnBasedMatch` instance that will return "`[Returns the limit the Game Center servers place on the size of the match data. (read-only)][1]`"

Answer (score -1):

```
According to documentation following is data size limit
1. Limit the size of unreliable messages to 1000 bytes or smaller in size.
2. Limit the size of reliable messages to 87 kilobytes or smaller in size.

[ http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html ]
```

Comment: This answer does not apply to turn based matches