# Do iOS Game Center turn based games use Apple servers?

Tags: ios, game-center

If I implemented a Game Center game on iOS using their turn based functionality will the game operate on Apple servers alone?

No further cost to me?

I'd probably use gkturnbasedmatch from what I've seen.

I am making an iOS board game and it occurred to me that I might be able to add online multiplayer.  The simplest and cheapest option for me would be if I could do it all from ios sdk.  I'm not interested in paying for a server.

If it does work then what are the limitations?

Please only provide an answer if it's current.  I think early Game Center was much more limited.  It might not have had gkturnbasedmatch for instance.

I am developing in iOS 8 and swift.

Comment: [Apple Docs - Turn-based Matches](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH15-SW1)

Comment: I did see this page.   But I'm looking for a quick simple answer.

Comment: Read the last paragraph of the first section. That document covers all your questions.

Comment: ? What is a section to you?  Please copy it to here.

Comment: When you implement turn-based matches in your game, the list of players, the data for matches, and other details are all stored on Game Center. Your game downloads this information as needed. Game Center is primarily responsible for storing data. You are responsible for providing the game logic that uses this infrastructure. In particular, you define: What data must be stored on Game Center When the match data needs to be updated When play passes to another player

Comment: So.  What about limitations?

Comment: How many players can be in a game?  How many games can a player be in at once?  Those type of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Apple Documentation on Turn-Based Matches](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH15-SW1).

> **Game Center is primarily responsible for storing data. You are
> responsible for providing the game logic that uses this
> infrastructure.** In particular, you define:
>
> What data must be stored on Game Center
>
> When the match data needs to
> be updated
>
> When play passes to another player

**Limitations:**

[Size of matchData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157171/maximum-size-of-gkturnbasedmatch-matchdata) - 64KB

Answer (score 1):

[Each player can participate in up to 30 simultaneous matches in a turn-based game.](https://devforums.apple.com/message/730998#730998)
Note that games that have ended still count until the user removes them (e.g. from the GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController).